# Matrix grid in MongoDB

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, matrix, mongoose

I'm trying to create a 2-dimensional matrix similar to the multiplications tables (image below), where the header column/row are user IDs, and the selected cell is an object containing information about the 2 selected users.

[image]

I could save an object for each user which contains an array of objects for all users, but that could get messy quickly with users being created/removed.

Hoping to keep this MongoDB. This also won't be accessed by the user so speed is not critical.

Comment: You'd have a collection with documents referring to both users. This is a well known pattern: relations with attributes.

Comment: But wouldn't it become a hassle to manage once there are thousands of users, new users being added, old ones being removed, etc.? I suppose I could have a cron job that could verify all valid users are being compared...

Comment: `db.matrix.remove({user1:userToBeRemoved});db.users.remove({_id:userToBeRemoved})`. Done for removal. As for the other stuff: you know your use case. But when you want to compare users, a static matrix would not be my choice.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks for your help